# How to make brace initialization and default values work together?

Tags: c++, initialization

The following code works

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    float f;
};


int main()
{
    A a{ 1, 0.1 };
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I add default values for A's members, it doesn't work

```
class A
{
public:
    int i = 0;
    float f = 3.14;
};
```

How to make both work together?

Comment: This will be fixed in C++14. As it stands, brace-or-equal initializers prevent a class from being an aggregate.

Comment: See [N3605](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3605.html), [N3653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3653.html).

Comment: To elaborate, Clang already has this fixed: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02bf800843cb1195

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a default and a custom constructor like the example below:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}  
    A(int const _i, float const _f) : i(_i), f(_f) {}
    int i = 0;
    float f = 3.14;
};
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4888d2a3d5fd03b2)

However as already mentioned by [@Kerek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb), [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in the comments this will be fixed in C++14 and your code will work as is.